# Unable to convert time using async.each() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I'm currently trying to process my batch of records using `each()` method in the module `async`  but I'm unable to do so. The data I'm reading is from aws Kinesis Data Streams.

Here is my code for the same

```
"use strict";
const {
  KinesisClient,
  GetRecordsCommand,
  GetShardIteratorCommand,
} = require("@aws-sdk/client-kinesis");
const { format } = require("date-fns");
const retry = require("async-retry");
const EventEmitter = require("events");
const async = require("async");

const kinesis = new KinesisClient({ region: "ap-south-1" });
const BUFFER_SIZE = 200;
let buffer = [];
let iterator;
const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

const pushToBuffer = (records) => {
  if (buffer.length >= BUFFER_SIZE) {
    eventEmitter.emit("bufferEvent", "The buffer is full.");
    return;
  } else {
    buffer.push(...records);
  }
};

const getShardIterator = async () => {
  const command = new GetShardIteratorCommand({
    StreamARN: "<my-arn>",
    ShardId: "<my-shard-id>",
    ShardIteratorType: "TRIM_HORIZON",
    StreamName: "<my-data-stream>",
  });
  const response = await kinesis.send(command);
  iterator = response.ShardIterator;
};

const readFromShard = async () => {
  try {
    const command = new GetRecordsCommand({
      ShardIterator: iterator,
      Limit: BUFFER_SIZE,
    });
    const response = await kinesis.send(command);
    const records = response.Records;

    if (records.length > 0) {
      const parsedRecords = records.map((record) =>
        JSON.parse(Buffer.from(record.Data).toString("utf-8"))
      );
      pushToBuffer(parsedRecords);
    }

    if (response.NextShardIterator) {
      iterator = response.NextShardIterator;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

const sleep = (ms) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};

const run = async () => {
  await getShardIterator();
  while (true) {
    try {
      await retry(
        async () => {
          await readFromShard();
          await sleep(5000);
        },
        {
          retries: 3,
          minTimeout: 1500,
          maxTimeout: 5000,
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
};

run();

const transformDate = async (record) => {
  let time = record.time;
  let timestamp = format(new Date(time), "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", {
    timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata",
  });
  return JSON.stringify({
    ...record,
    time: timestamp,
  });
};

const transformBuffer = async () => {
  try {
    await async.each(buffer, transformDate);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
  }
};
eventEmitter.on("bufferEvent", (message) => {
  console.log(message);
  transformBuffer();
  console.log(buffer);
  buffer = [];
});
```

2 functions `transformBuffer()` and `transformDate()` which has the code related to the date transformation.

The `time` field in the object remains the same.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!